# How do I include a multiplexer in a simple processor? VHDL Altera Quartus II

Tags: vhdl, cpu, cpu-architecture, processor, quartus

I'm currently creating a simple processor in VHDL code which includes: 10 16-bit registers, 1 9-bit register, an ALU, a control unit, a counter, bus lines  and a 16-bit multiplexer. I have every component ready but the multiplexer.

I want the multiplexer to be connected through the bus lines to the control unit and the 8 registers. How do I create the component and the architecture of this specific multiplexer?

Below is the link to a picture of the system I want to make (the rest of the system (the ALU, 9-bit register, etc.) is not drawn because it doesn't have any other connection to the multiplexer).
[image]

Comment: I do not understand how works your multiplexer. When one of the inputs R0out..R7out is asserted, one of the values of registers Rge0..Reg7 is at the output of the mux. But what is the purpose of DATAin?

Comment: @AlainMerigot The purpose of DATAin is to send 16-bit signals to the bus wires and transfer them to the Multiplexer.

Comment: Your explanation is not clear and you cannot implement anything without clear specs. A multiplexor is selector: output is one of the data inputs depending on control inputs. Control inputs are R0out..R7out? Data inputs are Reg0..Reg7? Probably DATAin is also a data input, but for which precise configuration of control inputs is it   transferred by the multiplexer?

Comment: tell as the input and the output of the multiplexer that you want with some example